# AVAudioSession routeSharingPolicy: ValidateRouteSharingPolicyParameters: category option(s) not supported

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, core-audio, avaudiosession

The following code for configuring an `AVAudioSession`'s `routeSharingPolicy` as `.longForm` is causing this error:

> [avas] AVAudioSession.mm:391:ValidateRouteSharingPolicyParameters: 0x44 category option(s) not supported in combination with AVAudioSessionRouteSharingPolicyLongForm

Can anyone help me understand why? It appears that all 3 of these `CategoryOptions` trigger the error (each with different hex values), but aren't they required in order to support AirPlay, etc.?

Removing them just seems to be avoiding the issue, rather than fixing it, and according to [this article](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/airplay_2/getting_airplay_2_into_your_app), setting the `routeSharingPolicy` to `.longForm` is a key part of the AirPlay setup process.

```
let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
var options = [AVAudioSession.CategoryOptions.allowBluetooth, AVAudioSession.CategoryOptions.allowAirPlay]
if mixWithOtherAudio {
    options.append(AVAudioSession.CategoryOptions.mixWithOthers)
}
try audioSession.setCategory(
    AVAudioSession.Category.playback,
    mode: AVAudioSession.Mode.default,
    policy: AVAudioSession.RouteSharingPolicy.longForm,
    options: AVAudioSession.CategoryOptions(options)
)
```

Comment: Did you figure this out by any chance?

Comment: Afraid not, sorry. Had to leave it as-is. Still welcome any solutions that people can find.

Comment: Check the bottom of this page.. it seems like we are using non-mirrored AirPlay on a category that does not allow it: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudiosession/category 
In my case PlayAndRecord Category.

Comment: Thanks for the input, but I don't think that's the issue in this example, because the category is being set to `AVAudioSession.Category.playback` and that documentation states "The audio session playback-only categories (ambient, soloAmbient, and **playback**) support both the mirrored and nonmirrored variants of AirPlay."